# IE not loading js and css files

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I wrote a website and included JS files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/app.js"></script>
```

Chrome loads all files correctly and website displayed correctly
IE doesn't load all JS and css files, (some parts are loaded and some are not) resulting in website not displayed correctly. 
IE version in all computers is 11.

I am also using these headers-

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: Can you open IE's console please? Just to confirm you are really getting a 404 (not found) when those files are called, as opposed to the code therein simply not working good on IE.

Comment: Could you supply a link to a page where we can see this not working?